# Upload image in firebase Storage using a link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload images in firebase storage. I know how to upload images in firebase using Uri. But is there a way in which I can upload images to firebase using a link?

I am using an API in my project and I can only hit it 1000 per month so I am trying to save images in firebase as soon as it is fetched from API.
the API gives a link to the image which I use to show images in imageview with Picasso.

suppose my link is http://xxx.xx.xxx.......png? I have converted it into Uri
using Uri.parse(link). Firebase gives me an exception when I try to do so.

The exception

```
StorageException: No content provider: http://xx.xx.com/xx/xx/xxx/xx/xx.png?
                                                                         java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://xx.xx.com/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx.png?
```

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Storage SDK will not work with remote files like that.  You can't pass it an HTTP URL and expect that it will download that remote file, then upload it to storage.  You have to download the remote file first, then upload it.

If it's not clear, the Uri that you pass it must refer to a local file only.